# Clip geometry in PyQGIS by not using a layer as an input

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have two vector geometries, geom1 and geom2. They do not exist as individual layers, but rather are derived out of additional scripting in PyQGIS.

I would like to clip geom1 with geom2.

From what I can tell, the only clipping functions available are the processing algorithms which - appear to only take individual layers as input. The geometries I have don't exist as individual layers, rather they have been derived via something similar to:

```
geom1 = feature.geometry()
```

The help for the clip algorithm (`processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:clip")`) suggests that the input and overlap need to be layers.

So the only solution I can see is to convert my geom1 and geom2, into temporary virtual layers, and then clip. This seems really really inefficient and I'm trying to work out if there is better way to do this.
Ideally something like:

```
clipped_result = clip(geom1, geom2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [`intersection()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a6ca0f918c7c67aff8ac9e0094707c99e) method of `QgsGeometry` is what you are after.

From the docs:

> Returns a geometry representing the points shared by this geometry and
> other.

So the analogue to your pseudocode is:

```
clipped_result = geom1.intersection(geom2)
```

i.e. the new geometry object stored in the return value `clipped_result` represents `geom1` clipped with `geom2`.

A simple example of usage:

```py
l = iface.activeLayer()
geom1 = l.getFeature(1).geometry()
geom2 = l.getFeature(2).geometry()
geom3 = geom1.intersection(geom2)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom3)
with edit(l):
    l.addFeature(feat)
l.triggerRepaint()
```

Screencast:

[image]

If you want to edit a feature's geometry in-place (clip a feature), you can do it at the layer level like:

```py
l = iface.activeLayer()
f1 = l.getFeature(1)
#print(f1.geometry())
f2 = l.getFeature(2)
geom3 = f1.geometry().intersection(f2.geometry())
with edit(l):
    l.changeGeometry(f1.id(), geom3)
l.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

There is also [`difference()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a2ba95f8ade7d34ce506f3929342d0611) method which

> Returns a geometry representing the points making up this geometry
> that do not make up other.

E.g.

```py
l = iface.activeLayer()
geom1 = l.getFeature(1).geometry()
geom2 = l.getFeature(2).geometry()
geom3 = geom1.difference(geom2)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom3)
with edit(l):
    l.addFeature(feat)
l.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Comment: ahhh ok - I kinda figured there would be a clip method, but this is definitely better than converting to layers. cheers for that.

Comment: whilst the intersect identifies the geometry in question, ideally - a clip method would return the clipped original geometry as an object as an output of the method call. ........ ie: identify partial geometries that will do the clipping (intersect), then remove this from current geometry and create a new geometry object as an output of the method...... using the above intersect works, but then ill have to perform geom.deletePart ......  im surprised it doesn't exist already as an encapsulated method. No biggy really.

Comment: @nr_aus, maybe I'm being really dense, but I still don't think I understand exactly what it is you want. I have updated my answer, but both these methods *do* return a new geometry object either with the shared or non-shared part of one input geometry and the other. I would really appreciate it if you would add an image to your question with some kind of visual representation showing what you think a clip method should return- I am just curious. Cheers.

Comment: sorry my previous comment was really badly worded and contradicts itself, so my bad there. Your suggestions aren't wrong, I just want them in one line! Im lazy! In a nirvana situation, "geom1 = clip(geom1, geom2)" or similar. I want the original geometry returned, but clipped, in an encapsulated clip method. So rather than having to test for spatial intersect and then perform deletePart of the intersect using a "with edit" call, as a two/three part process, I just want the original geometry returned, but clipped. A bit like how the 'Edit Features in Place' works on the Processing menu.

Comment: @nr_aus, Ok- no worries. Now I understand. AFAIK there is no such method available in the Python bindings.

Comment: no dramas, thanks for your help. I might turn this secondary piece into a new question.